# UA OPC Server data types

Tags: opc-ua

For the life of me I can't find out the answer to what I thought would have been a simple question - how to find the data typeof an OPC Node.

I'm writing a UA OPC library which involves creating a subscription and the monitoring/updating of tags within this subscription.

The request to write to a tag comes from an external application and consists of Subscription and tag ID together with an object value. The issue is that this object is invariably a string (don't ask), which needs to be converted to an appropriate data type for the tag. So, I need to find out what data type is associated with the tag. At the moment, the writing fails with a type mismatch exception.

Here's my update code:

```
//
    // Extension methods
    public bool Write<T>(long groupID, long tagID, T item)
    {
        var sub = FindSubscription(groupID);
        try
        {
            if (sub != null)
            {
                var node = sub.MonitoredItems.FirstOrDefault(m => (long)m.Handle == tagID);

                if (node != null)
                {
                    bool result = false;
                    var nodesToWrite = BuildWriteValueCollection(node.DisplayName, Attributes.Value, item);

                    StatusCodeCollection results;
                    DiagnosticInfoCollection diag;
                    try
                    {
                        _session.Write(
                        requestHeader: null,
                        nodesToWrite: nodesToWrite,
                        results: out results,
                        diagnosticInfos: out diag);


                        result = CheckReturnValue(results[0]);

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch  (Exception ex)
        {
            LogMessage(String.Format("Write GroupID {0}, Tag  {1}, Value {2}", groupID, tagID, item.ToString()), ex);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I've searched for ages to find out how to determine the data type of the node, but without success. So, for a MonitoredItem, how would one go about finding the data type so that I can convert the string to a compatible type?

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 1):

Read the `DataType` attribute of the `VariableNode` in question.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get that from a MonitoredItem - I can't see a DataType property?

Comment: From the MonitoredItem you take its NodeId and call the Read service asking for AttributeId.DataType. I don't know how nodeopcua works - it might not have read any more than the base attributes for you when you got a reference to the node, if any, so you need to actually go read the DataType attribute from the server.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info...and now I have a DataValue of 6 ? And this means? Sorry, but you have to realise you're talking to someone very, very dense. I've written a number of DA  client applications, but I'm astounded by how hard it is to find out such a simple and obvious data request... for each write (of which there could be many thousands a minute) I'm having to make a separate call to find out the data type of the node that I'm going to write to.... I HAVE the node, I KNOW the node, why would this (datatype) not be a default property of this node???

Comment: It *is* one of the built-in properties of a VariableNode, but in order to cut down on data transfer and complexity during a browse only the absolute essential attributes are returned. It's expected that client applications will either read the additional information they need as part of their browse process or on application startup. I can't tell what stack or toolkit you're using so I don't have any sort of idea what might be done for you.